# cordova plugin cannot resolve in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cordova, webpack

I'm trying to use `typescript`(I'm newbie in ts!) in a `cordova` project(version 8.0.0) but there is an error during `bundle index.ts`

> ERROR in ./www/js/index.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cordova-plugin-camera' in '....\CamApp\www\js'
>    @ ./www/js/index.ts 3:0-32
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 2
>   npm ERR! helloworld@1.0.0 bundle: `webpack --config webpack.config.js --source-map`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 2

here is my `webpack.conf.js`:

```
module.exports={
entry:"./www/js/index",
output:{ filename: "./www/dist/bundle.js"},
module:{
  rules:[{
      test: /ts$/,
      exclude:/node_modules/,
      use:[{
          loader:"awesome-typescript-loader",
          options:{
            configFileName:'tsconfig.webpack.json'
        }
      }]
  },
{
    test:/html$/,
    use:[{
        loader:"html-loader"
    }]
},{
    test:/css$/,
    use:[{
        loader:"css-loader"
    }]
}]
},
resolve:{
    extensions:[".ts",".js",".html",".css"]
},
devtool:"#inline-source-map"
```

}

and here is `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
        "es6",
        "dom"
    ],
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowJs": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "typeRoots": [
        "node_module/@types"
    ]
},
"exclude": [
    "plugins",
    "platforms",
    "node_modules",
    "typings",
    ".vscode"
]
```

}

I also imported plugin in `index.ts`. Is there anything that I might have forgot?

Comment: Can you post your `app.modules.ts` file? Thanks!

Comment: @jeffchef There isn't  such file in my project directory jeff, whats that?

Comment: @jeffchef And I must mention that I'm not using angular...

Comment: Would help me and anyone trying to answer if you could include your cordova version etc.

Comment: @jeffchef Yep! its 8.0.0